# libtiff: How to get values from the TIFFGetField routine?

Tags: c++, libtiff

I have a .tif file and would like to get the image width using libtif.
I have tried the following c++ code so far:

```cpp
TIFF* tif = XTIFFOpen(filenameStr.c_str(), "w");
if (!tif) {
    std::cout << "Error: failed to open file" << std::endl;
}
int32_t width = 0;

int test = TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

Running the code returns `0 \n "`. Thus, I'm able to open the tiff file but using the `TIFFGetField` routine doesn't seem to work. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? What do I have to do in order to write the width of that `.tif` file into my variable?
Unfortunately, I don't understand the [documentation](http://www.libtiff.org/man/TIFFGetField.3t.html) provided.
The .tif file is a regular picture that can be opened with app's. Thus, it has to have a width.

Comment: You are opening the file for writing?

Comment: @cgohlke Nice find! OP change `"w"` to `"rb"`.

Comment: according to the xtiff.c file I can open Tiff files as "w", "r" or "a". Opening it as "a" gives the same result and "r" actually throws the from me defined error message. How come I can open the .tif file with "w" or "a" but not with "r"? "rb" throws my error message as well.

Comment: You need to open it with *"read"* access for it to read the first IFD automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `TIFFGetField()` doesn't return a value. Instead it modifies the variable whose address you pass:

```
uint32_t width;

TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);
std::cout << width << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are correct, it writes a value "3435973836" to the variable width. But only if I open the .tif file in write mode. When I use "r" instead of "w" I get an access violation error. It works for now, so I'm happy but maybe there is a logical reason for that?

Comment: I didn't write the filename in the XTIFFOpen() function properly which was another major problem....